# What service recovery packages can be picked up at the self-service transfer kiosks at Amsterdam Schiphol Airport (AMS)?

Tags: air-travel, airport-transfer, ams, klm

I read on https://www.cheapflights.co.uk/news/self-service-transfer-kiosks-at-schiphol-airport ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20230102205401/https://www.cheapflights.co.uk/news/self-service-transfer-kiosks-at-schiphol-airport)), which explains the self-service transfer kiosks at Amsterdam Schiphol Airport (AMS):

> There will also be an opportunity for those eligible for service recovery packages to pick these up from the kiosks, in an attempt to dramatically improve customer experience.

What service recovery packages are they referring to?

Comment: It's worth noting that that post dates from over 15 years ago, so things may have changed a lot since then...

Answer (score 4):

From an [archive](https://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?d=4918682632131158&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=H0qOK8M32Vi8whEojkN_UaR8wxkwR1nG) of a VERY old Flyertalk post:

> KLM has introduced a new Service Recovery Package. The contents of the
> package, which will vary depending on the extent of the delay, include
> a letter of apology, a telephone card, a meal coupon, Flying Dutchman
> points or discount coupons for tax-free items, a discount coupon for a
> future KLM flight, and a questionnaire. With these product
> improvements, KLM takes another step forward in improving passenger
> service.

I guess it's some kind of hand-out if your flight is delayed or other related issue. The Flyertalk post is from 2002, and your link is from about 2007. Possibly things have changed since then.

Note that this was just the top result from a google search "service recovery package KLM" - I have no idea if it's the actual answer